# The problem with the theoretical understanding of the meaning in the Oracle DB rollback segments

Tags: linux, oracle

1. How is the optimal number of extents for rollback segments determined?
2. Where can you find information about this?
3. How does this happen? What is it for?

Oracle version:
[image]

I would be glad to receive your answers and advice! Can't find it anywhere.

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using?  "Rollback segments" is a pretty old term and configuring rollback segments isn't a thing that has been necessary in many, many years.  I'd need to go back to see exactly when Oracle transitioned from manual rollback segments to automatic undo management but it was many releases ago.

Comment: I am working with Oracle Linux Server release 6.5

Comment: That's the version of linux.  What version of the Oracle database are you using?

Comment: Forgive me for my carelessness and bad English. Edited the question and added an image with the version there :)

Comment: Ok, 11g should be using automatic undo.  Asking about rollback segments in 11g is like asking about spark plugs and carburetors on a diesel engine.

Comment: Yes, but the teacher made us do such laboratory work. Therefore, I can't seem to find any documentation on this topic :(

Comment: "can't seem to find any documentation" Maybe that's the point of the exercise. Ask the prof and tell him that kind of stuff hasn't been relevant much past version [7.3.4](https://www.oracle.com/servers/technologies/oracle7.html). The Server Concepts guide has plenty of references.

Comment: What other options are there for getting out of this situation? I already spoke about this to the teacher. He is persistent in his conviction :(

Comment: Oracle 11.2 doesn't have manual rollback segments.  You could potentially ask your professor if he is asking about how Oracle does automatic undo management.